# Adding arrow navigation buttons that fires keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay here is basically what I am trying to do
there is this [HTML 5 game](http://codepen.io/anthdeldev/pen/BHuGL) I want to add the support of navigation arrows like visual navigation that when clicked will do the same action as the keypress on the keyboard
I want when the button is clicked to fire event that do keypress right arrow

```
    <button type="button" id="right">></button>
```

JS

```
    var e = $.Event("keydown", {
        keyCode: 39
    });

    $( "#right" ).click(function() {
         $("body").trigger(e);
        console.log("right"); 
    });
```

Tried doing this but its not working

Comment: I suggest a refactor, but you're triggering wrong.. `$('body').trigger('keydown', {which: 39});` http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: I also recommend refactoring...  have a separate function, eg `handleDown()` and call that from the keydown/keypress event and from the button click event

Answer (score 0):

Change your click function to this and try:

```
$( "#right" ).click(function() {
     $('body').trigger("keydown", {which: 39});
    console.log("right"); 
});
```

But I would suggest you to trigger key events on input elements instead of body.